# Java bridge method can't be invoked on a non-injected object

Tags: java, android, android-webview

In my Android app I am using a WebView with setJavaScriptEnabled(true) and a JavaScript interface that gets callbacks.

I found that I get the error message `Java bridge method can't be invoked on a non-injected object` when I run code like the following.

My Java code has:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onResult(String json) {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(), "Android")
```

In the JavaScript of the WebView I am running:

```
let callback = Android.onResult
callback('test') //boom :(
```

But calling the callback generates the error.

Answer (score 7):

Wrapping with a function solved my problem:

```
let callback = function(res) { Android.onResult(res); }
callback('test')
```

I was able to get a tip from this comment, which pointed me in the correct direction:
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/323#issuecomment-511824940

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue.
In my case I had a `success` callback I needed to call (`window.Android.success`). My code looked somewhat like this:

```js
const triggerWebviewSuccessCallback = (message: string): void => {
  const androidCallback = window.Android?.success;
  const iosCallback = window.webkit?.messageHandler?.success?.postMessage;

  androidCallback?.(message);
  iosCallback?.(message);
};
```

In my case the assignment of `window.Android.success` to `androidCallback` was what caused the issue. The solution was simple (and can be written both shorter and cleaner): call the function directly without reassigning it

```js
const triggerWebviewSuccessCallback = (message: string): void => {
  const androidCallback = window.Android?.success;
  const iosCallback = window.webkit?.messageHandler?.success?.postMessage;

  if (androidCallback) {
    window.Android.success(message);
  }

  if (iosCallback) {
    window.webkit.messageHandler.success.postMessage(message);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been alluded to in the previous answers, the problem is that assigning the function to a variable changes the functions `this`.

Based on the discussion here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=514628 I found that it is possible to keep calling the function stored to a variable as in the original question using the .bind function which was useful for me as changing my code to call the function directly was not feasible.

```
let callback = Android.onResult.bind(Android)
callback('test')
```